# Create another train.txt to train sentiment model for other domains

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I find that data to train the sentiment model in train.txt is the PTB format looks like this.

```
(3 (2 Yet) (3 (2 (2 the) (2 act)) (3 (4 (3 (2 is) (3 (2 still) (4 charming))) (2 here)) (2 .))))
```

which the real sentence should be

```
Yet the act is still charming here.
```

But after parse I got the different structure

```
(ROOT (S (CC Yet) (NP (DT the) (NN act)) (VP (VBZ is) (ADJP (RB still) (JJ charming)) (ADVP (RB here))) (. .)))
```

Follows my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    // creates a StanfordCoreNLP object, with POS tagging, lemmatization, NER, parsing, and coreference resolution
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit,parse");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    // read some text in the text variable
    String text = "Yet the act is still charming here .";// Add your text here!

    // create an empty Annotation just with the given text
    Annotation annotation = new Annotation(text);

    // run all Annotators on this text

    pipeline.annotate(annotation);

    // these are all the sentences in this document
    // a CoreMap is essentially a Map that uses class objects as keys and has values with custom types
    List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);

    // int sentiment = 0;
    for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
        // traversing the words in the current sentence
        Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
        System.out.println(tree);
        // System.out.println(tree.yield());
        tree.pennPrint(System.out);
        // Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree.class);
        // sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree);
    }

    // System.out.print(sentiment);
}
```

Then two questions appear when I use my own sentences to create train.txt.

1.My tree is different than that in train.txt,I know the number in the latter one is the sentiment polarity.But it seems the tree structure is different, I want to get a binarized parse tree which might look like this

```
((Yet) (((the) (act)) ((((is) ((still) (charming))) (here)) (.))))
```

Once I get the sentiment number I can fill it in to get my own train.txt

2.How to get all phrases at each node of the binarized parse tree, in this example, I should get

```
Yet
the 
act
the act
is
still 
charming 
still charming 
is still charming
here
is still charming here
.
is still charming here .
the act is still charming here .
Yet the act is still charming here.
```

Once I got them I can spend money annotating them by human annotators.

Actually I googled them a lot,but couldn't work them out,so I post here.Any useful answers would appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the properties to get binary trees:

```
props.setProperty("parse.binaryTrees", "true");
```

The sentence's binary tree will be accessed this way:

```
Tree tree = sentence.set(TreeCoreAnnotations.BinarizedTreeAnnotation.class);
```

Here is some sample code I wrote up:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.Word;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SubTreesExample {

    public static void printSubTrees(Tree inputTree, String spacing) {
        if (inputTree.isLeaf()) {
            return;
        }
        ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
        for (Tree leaf : inputTree.getLeaves()) {
            words.addAll(leaf.yieldWords());
        }
        System.out.print(spacing+inputTree.label()+"\t");
        for (Word w : words) {
            System.out.print(w.word()+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (Tree subTree : inputTree.children()) {
            printSubTrees(subTree, spacing + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse");
        props.setProperty("parse.binaryTrees", "true");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        String text = "Yet the act is still charming here.";
        Annotation annotation = new Annotation(text);
        pipeline.annotate(annotation);
        Tree sentenceTree = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class).get(0).get(
                TreeCoreAnnotations.BinarizedTreeAnnotation.class);
        System.out.println("Penn tree:");
        sentenceTree.pennPrint(System.out);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Phrases:");
        printSubTrees(sentenceTree, "");

    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! If I want to train a Chinese sentiment model, the sentence in train.txt still needs to be binary parsed ? @StanfordNLPHelp